# Closed-form expression for Riemannian exponential maps on symmetric spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

Besides the Poincaré model for the hyperbolic disc, $S^n$, and Euclidean space, what are known instances of a symmetric space $M$ (finite-dimensional) for which the exponential map is known in closed-form?